# Quran in all qirats

Tags: quran, tafseer, reading-quran, uloom-al-quran, helping

Can anybody give me a link of any links or an app where one can read quran on all ten or just seven Qirats? Like that of hafs,ibn kathir, warsh?

Comment: I don't know of any app, but there are sites where you can find the Quran written in different Qiraat. Although, because of the lack of people checking over it, there may be mistakes there.

Comment: Can u name a few sites?

Answer (score 1):

You can find PDFs and audio recordings of the 10 qiraat on this website: [IslamWeb](https://audio.islamweb.net/audio/index.php?page=rewayat#)

However, note that I have found mistakes in their PDFs. It is always better to refer to an actual audio recitation.

You can also look at this mushaf which is written in the riwayah of Hafs from Aasim, and the other recitations are noted on the side: https://archive.org/details/msqammsqam/mode/2up

Answer (score 0):

In this I included some videos of same sura in different qiraat

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Zeqd3F35Usw

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=X0g1hQ75llw

What I would recommend is looking for quraa who recite in certain qiraa I think Alafasy recite in all of them!